Deserializing generic class with init-only setter in .NET 4.8 throws MissingMethodException
When I try to deserialize a generic class that contains init-only setters, I get the following exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in XML document (2, 2).'
Inner Exception:
MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Example.BrokenClass`1.set_MyString(System.String)'

However, deserializing non-generic classes with init-only setters works just fine.
What is the reason for this behavior? And is there any way to work around this problem without upgrading from .NET 4.8?
When I run the following minimal .NET 4.8 project, WorkingClass1 and WorkingClass2 deserialize without any problem. However, BrokenClass throws the previously mentioned exception.
Program.cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Example
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WorkingClass1<string> workingClass1 = new WorkingClass1<string>() { MyString = "Hello World" };
            TestXmlSerializer(workingClass1);

            WorkingClass2 workingClass2 = new WorkingClass2() { MyString = "Hello World" };
            TestXmlSerializer(workingClass2);

            BrokenClass<string> brokenClass = new BrokenClass<string>() { MyString = "Hello World" };
            TestXmlSerializer(brokenClass);
        }

        private static void TestXmlSerializer<T>(T myClass)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new(typeof(T));

            StringWriter writer = new();
            serializer.Serialize(writer, myClass);

            StringReader reader = new(writer.ToString());
            var output = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    public class BrokenClass<T>
    {
        public string MyString { get; init; }
    }

    public class WorkingClass1<T>
    {
        public string MyString { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkingClass2
    {
        public string MyString { get; init; }
    }
}

namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public static class IsExternalInit { }
}

Example.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>


You are targeting .NET 4.8, but what .NET and Visual Studio / VS Code versions are you building with?  Also 4.8?

I am using the latest Visual Studio 2022 v17.11.4

init was introduced in C# 9 but the last C# version supported natively by .NET Framework 4.8 is C# 7.3.  Your example works fine in .NET 8 (see here) so I reckon this must be a bug with the XmlSerializer code generator when 1) building using VS2022 2) targeting 4.8 3) generating XmlSerializers for generic classes that use language features from C# versions subsequent to C# 7.3 / .NET Framework 4.8

You could open an issue with MSFT about this, but I kind of doubt they will fix it.  As an alternative I'd suggest replacing your BrokenClass<T> with some BrokenClassDTO<T> DTO with get/set properties rather than get/init, then mapping the DTO to your final model.
